# Increase size of menu/toolbar icons in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, icons

The icons on top of the java windows are too small that it is hard to see, is there any way that i can enlarge that?

[image]

Comment: You can use Eclipse DevStyle Theme Icon Desginer ( https://www.genuitec.com/docs/workbench/devstyle-icon-designer/ )

Answer (score 8):

> There is no support in Eclipse for large/small icons in the toolbar.

The same question is here: [Eclipse: large toolbar icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669762/eclipse-large-toolbar-icons)

Maybe you can enable Windows compatibility for Eclipse. You can find more information in: 
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/10/11/dealing-with-eclipse-and-very-small-icons-on-ultra-high-density-displays/

Comment: FYI: If the question has been asked before, you should either leave a comment or vote to close the question as a duplicate.   Unless you intend to add more details or expand on the previous question, you should avoid "link only" answer

Comment: not only the eclipse but every window which involves java window has the problem

Comment: This solution is far cleaner and simpler than the "already answered" solution!  Use the link, Luke!

Comment: In Mac => Select Preferences => General => Appearance => Colors and Font => View and Editor Folders => Tree and Table for views => Edit