# increase eclipse toolbar icon size

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclips on Ubuntu 20.04. I found that font and icons size are too small.

When I run

```
GDK_DPI_SCALE=1.1 ./eclipse
```

Font size are ok but toolbar icons are still retaining small size:

[image: Small icons on toolbar]

When I tries to edit `e4_basestyle.css` files under `eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_X.X.X.vXXXXXXXX-XXXX\css` by adding

```
#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
#org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
    font-size: 16px;
    font: Nato Sans;
}

.MPart Tree {
    font-family: Nato Sans;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

it only affect on font.

Any options?

Comment: Does the following has an effect in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474802/6505250 By the way the font can also be changed in the preferences, no need to edit CSS files for that. Which Eclipse version do you have?

Answer (score 5):

Following this guy's answer;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61405677/13800339

At first, close eclipse and be sure it is closed. Than edit eclipse.ini and add the following lines:

> -Dswt.enable.autoScale=true

> -Dswt.autoScale=150

> -Dswt.autoScale.method=nearest

The -Dswt.autoScale=150 will increase your Icons, 150 will say 150%. If it is not enough, increase it or decrease it otherwise.

Comment: Doesn't work in Eclispe Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0). After adding this change, eclipse did not successfully launch (until I removed the change).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the existing switch `-Dswt.autoScale=200` doesn't work on all platforms.  Using autoScale may result in a broken eclipse UI. There is another way to increase the icon sizes without using the autoscale switch...

In the *Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 2023-09 (4.29.0)*, for every `blah.png` file under the `eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi` hierarchy, there is also corresponding `blah@2x.png` file which contains a larger version of the same icon.

I've read that SWT applications should automatically apply the `@2X` icons.  I suspect the SWT code that detects High-DPI is broken for some platforms, the use of the 2x icons should be automatic, but doesn't always work.

I forced the use of the larger icons by using the following Linux commands to rename each `blah@2x.png` to `blah.png` (which overwrites the original).

```
find eclipse/cpp-2023-09/eclipse/configuration   -iname '*@2X.png' | awk '{nf=$1; sub("@2x", "", nf); print "mv", $1, nf;}' | bash
```

You can preview the command actions without actually doing them by omitting the pipe-to-bash `| bash` on the end of the command line.

After restarting eclipse the icons on the toolbar are doubled in size.

Comment: Yes there is an switch as mentioned in my comment to the question.

Comment: As others have mentioned the `-Dswt.autoScale=200` switch doesn't work properly, at least not on some platforms.  I'll revise my answer to include that info.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.Thanks! FYI - you are missing a single quote in your command

Comment: Edited to add the missing quote.